# Why is it faster to get data from mysql than spring cache+redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis-cache

When I  use Spring cache it  takes more than twice as long as direct access to the database, but if I use `redistempla`  to  get data from Redis,  it is faster than MySQL.
so I can make sure that there is data in Redis ,

In addition, I just tested the query of a simple data,the project use Spring Boot and Spring Cloud with Redis cluster

his is my configuration

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate ObjectRedisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(ObjectRedisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300L);
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean(value="ObjectRedisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplates(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something is misconfigured but without more details, it would be hard to say what.

Comment: I  have added   more  details on  it ,  Could you check it out for me again，thx

Comment: Is your redis server running on another hosts that has larger latency than the MySQL server ?

Comment: You haven't described your problems clearly, there are many possibilities as I can see.
1. The cache has no data, it got data from database, so it became slowly.
2. You can examine your project, if your project structure has cache from database And more, it would be quickly when database has a few concurrence, you should test it when database become slow

Comment: I guess not, because I get the data directly from “redistemplate ” faster than mysql，